# C# Restful Client

Tags: c#, rest, console, client, wcf-rest

I have Implemented C# Restful Service and the service is running fine with this URL:
htp://port/restfulService.svc/json/?id=SHAKEEL"
and Result in Browser is:
Your Requested XML Product is :shakeel
I want to use this service for with the help of a Console Client, for that i implemented the following but not working, and IN result it is returning,
**Cannot send a Content-Body with this verb type**,
please provide me suggestions that may lead me to Solution.
Thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    do
    {
        try
        {
            string uri = "http://port/restfulService.svc/json/id=SHAKEEL";
            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
            req.KeepAlive = false;
            req.ContentLength = 0;
            req.ContentType = "text/xml";
            Stream data = req.GetRequestStream();
            data.Close();

            string result;
            using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            result = result.Substring(1, result.Length - 2);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?");
    } while (Console.ReadLine() == "Y");
}
```

Comment: see https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp

Answer (score 2):

A HTTP GET request can't send a body, so you should remove these lines:

```
req.ContentLength = 0;
req.ContentType = "text/xml";
Stream data = req.GetRequestStream();
data.Close();
```

Additionally, [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) provides a much simpler interface for basic interactions with a webserver.  Grabbing a string from a webrequest is as simple as:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) { 
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://port/restfulService.svc/json/id=SHAKEEL");
}
```

Comment: Dear, My problem resolved, but i want to know more details if you can share,
Thanks